# decrypt password in laravel 4

Tags: php, encryption, laravel-4.2

I need help. I'm using Laravel 4, I'm very new in laravel and i have 4 days in a row trying to solve this problem :(

I don't know how to decrypt a password to email it to the user and with it, activate his account.

I hope you can help me. Thanks.

My RegController.php:

```
//creates a key for 24h to activate account
$key = Str::random(32);
        Cookie::queue('key', $key, 60*24);
        Cookie::queue('email', $user->email, 60*24);    

        //creates url
        $msg = "<a href='".URL::to("registration/$user->email/$key")."'>Confirm acount</a>";

        $data = array(
            'user' => $user,
            'msg' => $msg,
            );

        $fromEmail = 'noreply@noreply.com';
        $fromName = 'Administrator';

        Mail::send('emails.register', $data, function($message) use ($fromName, $fromEmail, $user){
            $message->to($user->email);
            $message->from($fromEmail, $fromName);
            $message->subject('Confirm registration in Laravel');
        });
        $message = '<hr><label class="label label-info">we sent an email to confirm your registration</label><hr>';
        return Redirect::to('registro')->with('message', $message);
```

The view show in the email:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <h1>Welcome to the aplication Laravel</h1>
    <h1>Your user: {{$user->username}}</h1>
    <h1>Your password: {{$passworddecrypted)}}</h1>
    <p>Confirm your registration on this link:</p>
    {{$msg}}
</body>
</html>
```

I don't know how to decrypt in this part, when I send the email, the encrypted password always appears

Email example:

**Welcome to the aplication Laravel**

**Your user:** lalo

**Your password:** eyJpdiI6IllHZzFcL1hxaGNRd2w0UkRLZTdNMWt3PT0iLCJ2YWx1ZSI6IlJZMmkyeElYRVpka21cL25BU2ZrQ093PT0iLCJtYWMiOiI5ZTBlYTYzOTZjOTE0YmFkZDE4OTlkY2M1MjBiMGRmOGZkMWExYTE0MzI1MWNiN2FmMGM0ZjllMjcxZjVjZjYyIn0=

**Confirm your registration on this link:**

*Confirm registration in Laravel*.

Comment: that's probably a hashed password, and NOT something you can decrypt. at the very least, it's base64-encoded.

Comment: That's not supported OP. Laravel uses a non-reversible bcrypt hash.  Even if you could, it would _not_ be good practice to be sending passwords via e-mail as it is inherently unsafe

Comment: I´m saving the value in my DB like this:

    $user=new User;
   $user->password= Crypt::encrypt($password);

Comment: As you are encrypting the password yourself: why not send it before encrypting it ? (And I do not recommend this because it is kind of pointless to hash/salt/encrypt a password while sending it in plaintext in an email)

Comment: I don't know how to do that, could you tell me how? please?

Comment: Either you send the user his password BEFORE encrypting it, or don't send it at all. I recommend that last option.

Comment: well, i'm not sending the password anymore haha, thank you all for answering :D